# How to prove using epsilon-delta definitions that a function is continuous over a smaller interval

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm struggling to use the epsilon-delta definitions of continuity to show that
if $f(x)$ is continuous over the interval $(a,b)$ then is is also uniformly continuous of the interval $[a+1,b-1]$ and hence also uniformly continuous over the interval $(a+1,b-1)$.

If anyone could help that would be great cheers.

Comment: That is Heine's theorem which uses Bolzano.

Comment: I only know how to show that it is continuous in the first interval but not continue to mathematically show how it is continuous and hence uniformly continuous in smaller intervals by restricting the size.

Comment: Hint: A function that is continuous on a compact interval is uniformly continuous.